# Problems in calling Class within Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Whenever  I try to write the statement

```
Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity(), DetailActivity.class)...
```

it automatically changes to

```
Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity(), com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity.class)...
```

and Android studio says it cannot resolve symbol `app`.

What to do?

Comment: From which class are u trying to call the DetailActivity ?

Comment: post more code of this class and how your project look like.

Comment: Also post your imports

Comment: copy and paste com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity and put import in front of it at the top of your class, or right click it and click add static import